# Clustor block expection

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, articulate

I use articulate for building my chatbot. https://github.com/samtecspg/articulate

I get the below error when I execute `docker-compose up`

```
api_1            | 
api_1            | /usr/src/app/server/index.js:33
api_1            |     throw err;
api_1            |     ^
api_1            | [cluster_block_exception] blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/12/index read-only / allow delete (api)]; :: {"path":"/document/_mapping/document","query":{},"body":"{\"properties\":{\"document\":{\"type\":\"text\"},\"time_stamp\":{\"type\":\"date\"},\"maximum_saying_score\":{\"type\":\"float\"},\"maximum_category_score\":{\"type\":\"float\"},\"total_elapsed_time_ms\":{\"type\":\"text\"},\"rasa_results\":{\"type\":\"object\"},\"session\":{\"type\":\"text\"},\"agent_id\":{\"type\":\"integer\"},\"agent_model\":{\"type\":\"text\"}}}","statusCode":403,"response":"{\"error\":{\"root_cause\":[{\"type\":\"cluster_block_exception\",\"reason\":\"blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/12/index read-only / allow delete (api)];\"}],\"type\":\"cluster_block_exception\",\"reason\":\"blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/12/index read-only / allow delete (api)];\"},\"status\":403}"}
api_1            |     at respond (/usr/src/app/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/transport.js:308:15)
api_1            |     at checkRespForFailure (/usr/src/app/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/transport.js:267:7)
api_1            |     at HttpConnector.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/connectors/http.js:165:7)
api_1            |     at IncomingMessage.wrapper (/usr/src/app/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:4949:19)
api_1            |     at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:187:15)
api_1            |     at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:442:20)
api_1            |     at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1081:12)
api_1            |     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
api_1            | [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I've cleared 15gb of my space eventhough I get this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The indices probably became read-only.

Use the following command:

```
   curl -s -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -XPUT '[IP-server]:9200/_all/_settings?pretty' -d ' {
    "index":{
             "blocks" : {"read_only_allow_delete":"false"}
    }
}'
```