# Ran out of diskspace, now elasticsearch is broken in weird ways, how to debug?

Tags: elasticsearch

I had elasticsearch running, another program ran out of disk space. Now it's broken in many different ways. No clue how to debug.

1. Creating an index pattern in kibana just hangs
2. the logs shows `Unexpected error while indexing monitoring document` every few seconds
3. Read queries seem to be working, all indexed are green or yellow
4. Some indexes seem to error with `cluster_block_exception` for writing
5. Some indexes seem to write properly

What's my plan of action for figuring it out? I already did docker-compose down and up many times, as well as reboot, didn't help. Googleing `cluster_block_exception` and `Unexpected error while indexing monitoring document` doesn't seem to be related to my problem.

Comment: After running out of disk space, you trigger a write lock. Your answer lies here, disable the cluster setting for this write lock: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33369955/low-disk-watermark-exceeded-on

Comment: for cluster block exception: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55546176/clustor-block-expection/55547430#55547430